# O365 via PowerShell in ASP.NET MVC 3: MicrosoftOnlineException was thrown

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, powershell, office365

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 application which uses PowerShell to connect to Office 365 to retrieve some details about user licenses.

The code itself works in many cases:

- The project in my local IIS works
- A piece of code in LINQPad using the library works on my machine
- A piece of code in LINQPad using the library works on the target server

And where it doesn't work is of course the only place it really *should* work: The IIS on the target server.

I always get an Exception when calling the `Connect-MsolService` cmdlet. The problem is that the Exception doesn't tell me anything.

The Exception type is

`Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.MicrosoftOnlineException`

and the message is

> Exception of type 'Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.MicrosoftOnlineException'  was thrown

which is pretty useless.

The Office 365 user account I use in my code is always the same. The user account used to start the IIS is always the same, too (Local System).

I wrapped the PowerShell code execution in a class named `PowerShellInvoker`. Its code can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/Gqd9nMw1).

And here is the code that connects to Office 365:

```cs
var cred = new PSCredential(upn, password);

_psi = new PowerShellInvoker("MSOnline");
_psi.ExecuteCommand("Connect-MsolService", new { Credential = cred });
```

There is no Exception actually *thrown*, the error is found in the `Error` property of the pipeline. (See lines 50ff. of the `PowerShellInvoker` class.)

The problem is that I don't know what could be wrong, especially because the same code works when I use LINQPad. The search results by Google couldn't help me either.

The server runs on Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter SP1 with IIS 7.5.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the solution!

I don't know the reason, but on the target server, the app pool's advanced settings for my app had set **Load User Profile** to `False`. I changed it back to `True` (which should be default) and voilà, it works!

***Edit:*** The **Load User Profile** setting was apparently automatically set to `False` by default because the IIS 6.0 Manager was installed and `False` was the default behavior until IIS 6.0.

Comment: I honestly can not even remotely describe how thankful I am that you actually came back and answered this question.  I spent like 2 days trying to track this down... seriously I can not thank you enough!